# How to properly scroll after cells were added/removed to UITableView with RxSwift

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a view controller with `tableView` with one section and I am displaying `data` in it using RxSwift in a following way. I wanna scroll to bottom of the `tableView` (or to anywhere else) whenever the `data` change. I am using `.xib` files for my cells and animated data source.

The problem is, that sometimes when calling `scrollToRow` the cell is not yet displayed in the `tableView` and the call throws an error.

**How to solve this?**

The only thing I can think of is putting a delay between data change and scroll, but how big should the delay be? Also I would think that there is some more robust way to solve this. Somehow waiting until the cell is actually displayed.

I tried doing:

- `scrollRectToVisible(...)` to the bottom of `tableView.contentSize`
- checking if `data.count == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)` before scrolling

Either of them results in the `tableView` sometimes not scrolling when `data` was updated, which is better than error, but still not the desired outcome.

```
class SomeVC: UIViewController {
    private typealias DataSource = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<AnimatableSectionModel<..., ...>>

    private let db = DisposeBag()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private let data = BehaviorRelay<[...]>(value: ...)
    
    private lazy var dataSource = createDataSource()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: ..., bundle: ...), forCellResuseIdentifier: ...)
        dataSource.animationConfiguration = AnimationConfiguration(insertAnimation: .bottom, reloadAnimation: .fade, deleteAnimation: .fade)

        data
            .asDriver()
            .do(afterNext: { [unowned self] data in
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    let lastIndexPath = getLastIndexPath(from: data)
                    // This does not always hold: data.count == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
                    self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
                }
            }
            .map { [AnimatableSectionModel(...)] }
            .drive(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
            .disposed(by: db)
    }

    private func getLastIndexPath(from data: [...]) {
        // Something like this
        return IndexPath(row: data.count - 1, section: 0)
    }

    private func createDataSource() -> DataSource {
        return DataSource(configureCell: { dataSource, tv, indexPath, model in
            let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ..., for: indexPath)
            ...
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put this assert in the `afterNext:` - `assert(sections[0].items.count == tableView!.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))` Does it ever fire?

Answer (score 1):

The following works but it is not ideal:

```
source
    .map { [SectionModel(model: "", items: $0)] }
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

source
    .filter { $0.count > 0 }
    .map { IndexPath(row: $0.count - 1, section: 0) }
    .bind(onNext: { [tableView] indexPath in
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The important point, and the big problem, here is that the two subscriptions depend on order. Since they are not independent, if you reverse them the app won't work.

This also worked for me. Maybe you are calculating the last row incorrectly?

```
source
    .map { [SectionModel(model: "", items: $0)] }
    .do(afterNext: { [tableView] sections in
        if sections[0].items.count > 0 {
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: sections[0].items.count - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    })
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: No this is definitely not working for me. Its super hard to reproduce the error, it works almost every time, but not every time. I am sure I am calculating the index path correctly (backed up by the fact that scrollRectToVisible also sometimes does not scroll). Do u have any guesses on why it should not work? Could it be the asDriver(), .xib or maybe the AnimatedDataSource? It seems to happen when there is multiple changes in the source observable at once